# creating an std::array with size calculated during run time

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, stdarray

I want to create an object of `std::array<T, N>` but the problem is I can only use functions that return a `constexpr`type or compiler will complain. The problem here is that I need to calculate the length of this array based on another array's size which could be something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct DataLength 
{
    template <typename iter>
    size_t maxPossibleLength(iter begin, iter end) 
    {
        size_t m_size = 0;
        while (begin != end) {
            m_size = m_size << 8 | std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); /* 0xff for uchar*/
            begin++;
        }
        return m_size;
    }
}
```

how can i convert the output of this function so i can use it instead of `N`?

Comment: `std::array`'s size must be known at compile time. The run-time-sized array is `std::vector`.

Comment: As T.C. says, the answer to your question is "You can't create a `std::array` with size calculated at run time." You can either use `std::vector`, or give us some more information about the problem you are trying to solve so we can suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: it would be nice to state the reason for the down vote. There's no problem with my question the problem is the C++ language capabilities.

Comment: The actual question is why there is no way to make a constant-length `vector`. It is a good question, but one that cannot be answered in SO.

Comment: @Elazar I didn't know it's impossible. If i knew I wouldn't ask it in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write this as a recursive `constexpr` function, and do the calculation on the length of the original array, which should be compile time too.

The thing is that your function (if i understood it correctly) need not get an iterator at all. It needs a length N. so it can do something like:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr size_t maxLength(size_t n, size_t m_size=0) {
    return n==0 ? m_size : maxLength<T>(n-1, m_size << 8 | std::numeric_limits<T>::max());
}
```

And it runs:

```
std::array<int, 15> a;
std::array<float, maxLength<int>(a.size())> b;
```

Comment: I didn't get your point could you please elaborate it with an example?

Comment: It is not imprtant. Whatever you need it to be.

Comment: the compiler complains about the value of `n` not being initialized with a constant expression. I mean i can't call this function with `maxLength(some_array.size())`.

Comment: your answer did not solve my problem but I learned a new technique which is using recursion in `constexpr` functions.